# Putting Chatter: feedwithfollowers to be custom object/ visualforce page specific

Tags: apex, chatter

Hi we are using chatter: feedwithfollowers like this below:

```
<chatter:feedwithfollowers entityid="{!$User.Id}"></chatter:feedwithfollowers>
```

however this shows everything posted into salesforce, im not really sure if its possible to have the feedwithfollowers visualforce/custom object specific??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can definitely do this. All you need to do is change the `EntityId` to point to your specific custom object:

```
<chatter:feedwithfollowers entityid="{!customObject.Id}"></chatter:feedwithfollowers>
```

[Documentation](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_chatter_feedWithFollowers.htm):

> Entity ID of the record for which to display the feed; for example, `Contact.Id`

Comment: i tried doing entityid="{!productcomponent__c.id}" and {!productcomponent__r.id}" both come back unknown markup?

Comment: You need to make sure that productcomponent__c is a variable in your controller/extension. Also, make sure that you have feed tracking turned on for that object type.

Comment: Thanks noticed id called productcomponent something entirely different in the controller, looong day thats fixed it :)